# R split data into categories

Tags: r

I am trying to find the most efficient way to split a list of numbers into bins by value and then calculate a cumulative sum for each successive category.

I can't seem to get the value categories from this for the plot.

```
> scores
 [1] 115 119 119 134 121 128 128 152  97 108  98 130 108 110 111 122 106 142 143 140 141 151 125 126
> table(cut(scores,breaks=10))

(96.9,102]  (102,108]  (108,113]  (113,119]  (119,124]  (124,130]  (130,136]  (136,141]  (141,147]  (147,152] 
         2          1          4          1          4          5          1          2          2          2 

> cumsum(table(cut(scores,breaks=10)))
(96.9,102]  (102,108]  (108,113]  (113,119]  (119,124]  (124,130]  (130,136]  (136,141]  (141,147]  (147,152] 
         2          3          7          8         12         17         18         20         22         24 

> plot(100*cumsum(table(cut(scores,breaks=10)))/length(scores),ylab="percent of scores")

> lines(100*cumsum(table(cut(scores,breaks=10)))/length(scores))
```

This produces an acceptable plot, which contains index values (2,4,6...). How can I get the values 96.9, 102, etc... Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `xaxt = "n"` to force the `plot` not to display the x axis labels, and display them by yourself using `axis` while retrieving them using `names`

```
plot(100*cumsum(table(cut(scores,breaks=10)))/length(scores),ylab="percent of scores", xaxt = "n")
lines(100*cumsum(table(cut(scores,breaks=10)))/length(scores))
axis(1, 1:10, names(table(cut(scores,breaks=10))))
```

[image]