# How to split data up using an if statement?

Tags: r

I have a data set in R that involves students and GPAs, for example

```
Student       GPA
Jim           3.00
Tom           3.29
Ana           3.99
```

and so on.

I want a column that puts them in a bin. for example

```
Student       GPASplit
Jim           3.0-3.5
Tom           3.0-3.5
Ana           3.5-4.0
```

Because when I try to take the statistics for the GPA all the bins are seperated based on the actual GPA. For example I am trying to find the percentage for how many students have higher than a 3.5, a GPA between 3.0-3.5, and so forth. But I get the percentage in terms of the actual GPA and when you have 4000 data points all with different GPAs, it is hard to figure out how many have a GPA higher than 3.5 and so forth? Does this make sense? Sorry if it doesn't.

Comment: Did you try using `?cut`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664942/r-split-data-into-categories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `cut()` function to split data into bins that you define. You have to be careful about values that fall exactly on the boundaries though, and make sure they're being treated how you want. With your example data:

```
> df$GPA_split = cut(df$GPA, breaks = c(3.0, 3.5, 4.0), include.lowest = TRUE)
> df
  Student  GPA GPA_split
1     Jim 3.00   [3,3.5]
2     Tom 3.29   [3,3.5]
3     Ana 3.99   (3.5,4]
# Count values in each bin
> table(df$GPA_split)

[3,3.5] (3.5,4] 
      2       1
```